# Python RANDOM always got same result

Tags: python, random, telegram

I have this code ⬇️ in a Telegram bot (whit telebot).
When I send /start it send a random element but It send always the same

```
v1 = "1111"
v2 = "ABCD"
v3 = "EFGH"
v4 = "XXXX"
v5 = "0000"

list = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5]
abcd = random.choice(list)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, abcd)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Side note: `list` is syntax highlighted differently here because it's a built-in type with a constructor `list()`. It's a good idea not to shadow such built-ins. Consider calling your list `lst` or `list_` or, even better, something semantically valid like `fruits` or `baseball_teams` or whatever makes sense for your real use case.

Answer (score 3):

You select a value only once. Replace `bot.reply_to(message, abcd)` with `bot.reply_to(message, random.choice(list))` to get random result every time.

Comment: It works!
Thanks

Comment: Then, could you accept my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, random.choice(['1', '2', '3', '4']))
```

I think it is better to use a smaller amount of variables and the variable name `list` is a built-in class
also check if you have a
`random.seed()`
in your code